# Vim netrw source session error?

Tags: vim, temporary-files, netrw

I set netrw `let g:netrw_liststyle = 3` in my `.vimrc`.

Then open vim, run `:e /tmp` and `:mksession!`.

And I open v`im` again, run `:so Session.vim`, can't list right `netrw`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The netrw plugin uses a so-called *scratch buffer* to display the file listing. The contents are not persisted to disk; instead, they are created and updated dynamically by the plugin.

Sessions are meant for "normal" buffers that are backed up by files; most plugins don't play well with them. Some session manager plugins have explicit support for certain plugins, but in general, it is recommended to close any plugin windows before creating a session, and reopening those after session restore.